# Firebase Cloud Functions: Function timeout on triggers

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a scheduled function that writes data to Firestore on an hourly basis and also have a `onCreate` trigger function listening for any documents newly added to Firestore. When a document is added to a collection, the `onCreate` function gets triggered and then performs a web scraping task. Once the webscraping task completes, it then writes more data to the document.

All is good but I am encountering periodic function timeout for the `onCreate` function. See logs:
[image]

I observed that these function timeout only occur when there are about more than 30 `onCreate`s being triggered, ie writing more than 30 documents to Firestore all at once. Otherwise, those functions would most likely be executed successfully.

This is how I write the documents to firestore:

```
function addToFirestore(item) {
    let ref = firebase.db.collection('items')
    let id = ref.doc().id
    return ref.doc(id).set(item)
}

//Usage
//Here, items.length ranges between 20 to 200
let promises = items.map(item => addToFirestore(item))
return Promise.all(promises)
```

And here is the `onCreate` trigger function:

```
//onCreate listener
module.exports = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    let item = snap.data()
    return scraper.start(item) //Webscraping task   
})
```

Is there a limitation on the number of triggers Firestore can take? If so, how can I perform some sort of 'batch triggers' so that it doesn't handle voluminous `onCreate` triggers?

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what's going wrong.  It could just be that the scraping task really is just taking more then 60s to complete.  Cloud Functions can run 1000 concurrent invocations of a single function, so capacity is not a problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your input. I will investigate further on the scraping task

Comment: I'm also having `onWrite` triggers timeout after 60 seconds. When I go to Google Cloud Console to check the corresponding Google Cloud Function for the Firebase Cloud Function and click edit, I see the setting of 60 seconds timeout. @DougStevenson, I see you have answered in multiple places that there should not be a timeout but there is.

Comment: Oh, also in Firebase console I see that all Firebase Cloud Function entries have the 60s timeout on the rightmost column. Both HTTP functions and trigger functions.